# Move rows or columns with keyboard shortcuts in Numbers

Tags: keyboard, numbers

Looking for a way to move rows and columns using the keyboard. This would obviously be based on the currently-selected cell — regardless of whether or not the row or column is selected.

On a related note, looking for a keyboard shortcut to select the row or column of the currently-selected cell.

Answer (score 2):

### AFAIK you can't.

The closest you can get is highlighting a row/column/cell, and long-pressing (or force touching) then dragging, to insert/replace somewhere else. Also, highlight one of the above and pressing `Option-ArrowKey` (substitute `ArrowKey` for an arrow key) to insert a row/column/cell in the direction of the arrow key.

Here is a link to the [Numbers Keyboard Shortcuts](https://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/5.2/index.html?localePath=en.lproj#/tana45192591) help.

Comment: Yeah I am familiar with all the keyboard shortcuts to insert rows/columns, as well as how to move them around with the mouse. Specifically looking for possibly overlooked methods to move rows and columns using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Cut the rows, delete them, and then elsewhere insert them from the clipboard.

First assign a keyboard shortcut in System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. For the **Numbers** application and menu title **Copied Rows**, add a shortcut such as <kbd>⌃⌘V</kbd>.

Then in Numbers,

1. Select source rows: <kbd>⌥⌘⏎</kbd>, <kbd>⇧↓</kbd>
2. Cut: <kbd>⌘X</kbd>
3. Delete rows: <kbd>⌥⌘⌫</kbd>
4. Select insertion point
5. Insert copied rows: <kbd>⌃⌘V</kbd>